# Is there an extension for Visual Studio Code that formats .bat files?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, batch

I've been looking around to format/prettify `.bat` files in Visual Studio Code but it seems none of the extensions that I found in Marketplace are able to do that. Am I missing something when I'm looking it up? I've used keywords such as `.bat`, `batch format`, `batch beautify`, `batch prettify`, `.bat format`, `.bat beautify`, `.bat prettify`.

I have also been googling, but no results seem to come up when using such as `batch format vscode`, `batch beautify vscode`, `batch prettify vscode`, `.bat format vscode`, `.bat beautify vscode`, `.bat prettify vscode` that are compatible with Visual Studio Code.

Even though after restarting VSCode after I installed some extensions that seemed related to `.bat` formatting and pressing Alt + Shift + F while a .bat file was open, nothing would happen, always getting this prompt:

```
There is no formatter for 'bat' files installed.
```

Do you know of any extension that formats `.bat` files?

Thanks!